# Finding best location to put facility within network so all points are near facility using ArcMap Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, location-allocation

Suppose I have many points distributed in a network. I want to place three facilities in the best way so that all points are near a facility.

How can I do it using ArcMap and ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some background and description of the ArcGIS Network Analyst process can be found at Esri's help pages for [Location-allocation analysis](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004700000050000000) and [Solving a location-allocation problem in ArcMap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/in_ArcMap/004700000051000000/).

The relevant tool is [Make Location-Allocation Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004800000009000000).

> After creating the analysis layer with this tool, you can add network analysis objects to it using the Add Locations tool, solve the analysis using the Solve tool, and save the results on disk using Save To Layer File tool