# Selection of best site for factory in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin, qgis-network-analysis, location-allocation

I am stuck trying to determine, where it would be preferable to locate one or more factories according to the data shown below.

The criterias for the selection of the site(s) are:

1. There must be 15 demand points within a range of 50 km from the factory.
2. The factory must not be more than 1 km from a highway
3. The factory must not be more than 5 km from a settlement

I would prefer that the distances is meassured along the roads, but it's not necessary.

Right now I have:

1. A vector later of the road network
2. Point layer with the existing factory.
3. Grid with demand (I also have a point layer for demand, if that is preferable).
4. A polygon layer of settlements.

[image: Fabric = Factory :-)]

I know there is a tool in ArcMap, which is called "Location-Allocation", which is useful. I have been inspired by this post: https://gisgeography.com/optimal-business-location-allocation/ but I don't have an ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Network Analyst license.

Can I get to the result I am seeking using QGIS?

I have been looking into these Q&As , but I don't see that they give me a solution in QGIS:

- [Finding best location to put facility within network so all points are near facility using ArcMap Network Analyst](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124307/how-to-find-the-best-location-to-put-a-facility-within-network-so-that-all-point)
- [Open source location allocation modelling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9246/open-source-location-allocation-modelling)

Comment: You have a diverse range of tags on this question. What is your *specific* problem? Have a read of [how to ask a good question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to focus on a particular issue. Include all information necessary to the reader and include details about what you have already tried and where exactly you get stuck.

Comment: Hey Matt. Thank you, for the feedback - I have taken it into account. I have different tags, because I am trying to relate the question to a given solution? Anyway, I hope you will open the question again, as I need help.

Comment: You need to start by defining some criteria. What do you consider to be a good location? Should the factory be in a region of high demand, or should it be within reach of (for example) 10 regions of low demand. What is 'in reach'? Is it distance, drive time..? Does it need to be near a major highway, does it need to be near water? There is an indeterminable number of variables that we as readers have no knowledge of, so, unfortunately, it makes it nigh on impossible to answer your question as it is currently written. What in the ArcGIS `Location Allocation` tool do you wish to emulate?

Comment: Hi Matt. Once again, thank you for your respons. I guess it is obvious that I am new in the community... :-) I have edited the post with some more information and criterias - hope it makes it more easy to help! As it also appears in the question (now), have I been inspired by this post: https://gisgeography.com/optimal-business-location-allocation/

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that Location-Allocation in ArcGIS does what you want.  I have not been able to find anything in QGIS that does what you want.

Have you considered using QGIS to create an OD matrix to use as input into a mixed integer program?  I just created an MIP for a problem like this, and it's quite simple. The plugin QNEAT3 can help you create the OD matrix.

Here's what my GNU MathProg code looks like for a similar problem I created for testing purposes.   It considers 500 possible origins and 20 destinations, and seeks to minimize cost (could be travel time or distance).  On my computer, it solves in just over 1 second. I used the GUSEK IDE for GLPK to do this. I haven't included the 10,000+ lines of data.

```
set S; # source (bits of township)
set F; # potential facilities (cities, towns, villages).

param m{s in S}; # biomass (Mg) available from each source
param k{f in F}; # capacity {Mg of biomass} of each potential facility
param c{s in S, f in F}; # cost of moving biomass from s to f ($/Mg}
param n; # number of facilities to build
param bigM; # a big number for binary switches (must be bigger than biggest k)


/* --------- Decision variables ----- */
var p{s in S, f in F} >= 0 <=1; # proportion of m moving from s to f
var b{f in F} binary; # binary variable indicating if facility f is built

/* ---------- Accounting variables -----------*/
var u{f in F} >= 0; # used capacity in f

/* ---------- Objective function ----------*/
minimize cost: sum{s in S, f in F} ( c[s,f] * m[s] * p[s,f] ); # minimize cost   

/*----------- number of facilities constraint ---------*/
subject to facilities:  sum{f in F} b[f] = n;

/* ---------- Accounting constraints ------*/
subject to prod{f in F}: sum{s in S} ( m[s] * p[s,f] ) - u[f] = 0;

/* ---------- Switching constraints ----- */
# biomass can only go to facility if it is built.
subject to switch{f in F}: u[f] - bigM * b[f] <= 0;

/*----------- fill to capacity constraints ------------ */
subject to fill{f in F}: u[f] >= k[f] * b[f];

/*------------ use no more than 1.0 proportion ---------*/
subject to resource{s in S}: sum{f in F} p[s,f] <= 1.0;

solve;

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

printf: "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", 'facility','source','prop','tons','cost' > "demo.txt";  
for {f in F}        
{       
    for {s in S}    
    {   
        printf: "%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\n", f,s,p[s,f],p[s,f]*m[s],c[s,f] >> "demo.txt";
    }   
}   

/* --------------------------------------------------------------- */

data;
```